# Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

Developing a project at the moment and have the CS1061 C# 'object' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I can't use any of the other options that comes up as it doesn't make sense to use those. Below is the class which this error occurs on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BookPianoLessons.Models;
using BookPianoLessons.Models.Catalog;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PianoData;
using PianoData.Models;
using PianoDataService;

namespace BookPianoLessons.Controllers
 {
public class CatalogController : Controller
{
    private PianoAsset _assets; 

    public CatalogController(PianoAsset assets)
    {
        _assets = assets; 
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var assetModels = _assets.GetAll();

        var listingResult = assetModels
            .Select(result => new AssetIndexListingModel
     {
                ID = result.ID,
                imageURL = result.imageURL, 
                title = result.title,
                teacher = _assets.GetTeacher(result.ID),
                grades = result.Grades,
                examBoards = result.ExamBoards,

        });
        var model = new AssetIndexModel()
        {
            Assets = listingResult
        };

        return View(model);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you single out which line of code you get that error on?

Comment: It should be `Select` and not `select` if that's not a typo from typing the code in.

Comment: it's still an error even if I have a capital s

Comment: @zer0 it's this one .Select(result => new AssetIndexListingModel

Comment: @ChloeMcMullan Any chance you can provide code I can run myself to reproduce?  Then I could fix.  The issue doesn't seem related to `DbContext`, or related, so you could just make some classes, populate with bogus data, and then the LINQ statement throwing the error.

Comment: do you have an email that i can send you a link to a zip folder i have for the project on google drive?