# Receiving an object definition error related to using a dictionary object created from an XML file

Tags: c#

I'm developing a hobby project that communicates with external hardware (a robot), and am stuck with a few compiler errors that I can’t resolve.

Now before a mod closes this because other questions with this error have been asked, I have read numerous posts about other users CS1061 errors (e.g. [Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745670/error-cs1061-object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-and-no-accessible-extens)), as well as relevant support documents (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061)). However, the level of expertise/experience in these previous questions is beyond my ability to comprehend and apply to my specific problem (or maybe I'm just daft and can't figure this out). I am in need of specific guidance explaining how to address my particular problem.

Ok, getting down to it. The errors are:

error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Connection' and no accessible extension method 'Connection' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Devices' and no accessible extension method 'Devices' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and occur on lines 7, 9, 15, 30, and 32 in the 1st code block below.

They seem to be related to data in the Xml (Connection and Devices) not being correctly recognized/stored in the object "value" (or value2). For background, the Xml file (3rd code block below) is read into a dictionary using the XmlSettings class, which I've provided in the 2nd code block below.

```
XmlSettings xmlSettings;
xmlSettings = new XmlSettings();
xmlSettings.Load();
if (xmlSettings.TryGetValue("Cambus", out var value))
{
    string text;
    text = this.CameraConnection ?? value.Connection;
    this.systemConfiguration = new List<RaspDeviceConfiguration>();
    if (string.Empty.Equals(value.Devices))
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        foreach (dynamic item in (IEnumerable<object>)value.Devices)
        {
            Type type;
            type = Type.GetType((string)item.Impl, throwOnError: true);
            if (typeof(IRaspComponent).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                this.systemConfiguration.Add(new RaspDeviceConfiguration(type, item.Role, text, item.Address, item.Configuration));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        this.systemConfiguration = null;
        throw;
    }
}
if (xmlSettings.TryGetValue("Mountarm", out var value2) && ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value2.Connection)) ? true : false))
{
    this.ServoConnection = value2.Connection;
}
```

XmlSettings is a public class that loads an Xml file with various hardware settings. TryGetValue is a function within the XmlSettings class, and value is of type object.

Below is the XmlSettings code:

```
public class XmlSettings
{
    private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(XmlSettings));

    private ExpandoObject expandobj;

    public void Load()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(XmlSettings).Assembly.Location), "RaspCamModuleSettings.xml");
        Load(path);
    }

    public void Load(string path)
    {
        log.DebugFormat("Loading settings from {0}", path);
        expandobj = _getExpandobjFromXml(path);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string property, out object value)
    {
        if (expandobj != null)
        {
            return ((IDictionary<string, object>)expandobj).TryGetValue(property, out value);
        }
        value = null;
        return false;
    }

    private static dynamic _getExpandobjFromXml(string file, XElement node = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file) && node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        node = ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file)) ? XDocument.Load(file).Root : node);
        IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = new ExpandoObject();
        PluralizationService pluralizationService = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"));
        foreach (XElement gn in node.Elements())
        {
            bool flag = gn.HasElements && ((gn.Elements().Count() > 1 && gn.Elements().All((XElement e) => e.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == gn.Elements().First().Name.LocalName)) || gn.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == pluralizationService.Pluralize(gn.Elements().First().Name.LocalName).ToLower());
            List<XElement> obj = (flag ? gn.Elements().ToList() : new List<XElement> { gn });
            List<object> list = new List<object>();
            foreach (XElement item in obj)
            {
                list.Add(item.HasElements ? _getExpandobjFromXml(null, item) : _extractNodeValue(item));
            }
            dictionary[gn.Name.LocalName] = (flag ? list : list.FirstOrDefault());
        }
        return dictionary;
    }

    private static object _extractNodeValue(XElement node)
    {
        object obj = node.Value.Trim();
        XAttribute xAttribute = node.Attribute("clr-type");
        if (xAttribute != null)
        {
            string text = xAttribute.Value.Trim();
            if (!text.Contains('.'))
            {
                text = "System." + text;
            }
            Type type = Type.GetType(text, throwOnError: true, ignoreCase: true);
            obj = Convert.ChangeType(obj, type);
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Lastly, to help contextualize, the Xml settings file (RaspCamModuleSettings.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DeviceConfig>
    <Cambus>
        <Connection></Connection>
        <Devices>
            <Device>
                <Role>camera1</Role>
                <Address clr-type="int32">15</Address>
                <Impl>Rasp.Core.RaspCamComponent,Rasp.Core</Impl>
                <Configuration>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                    <CamConfigurations>
                        <CamConfiguration TargetProductNumber="711">
                            <Diagflags0Mask>2024</Diagflags0Mask>
                            <OptionToggles>0</OptionToggles>
                        </CamConfiguration>
                    </CamConfigurations>
                    ]]>
                </Configuration>
            </Device>
            <Device>
                <Role>camera2</Role>
                <Address clr-type="int32">18</Address>
                <Impl>Rasp.Core.RaspCamComponent,Rasp.Core</Impl>
                <Configuration>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                    <CamConfigurations>
                        <CamConfiguration TargetProductNumber="711">
                            <Diagflags0Mask>2024</Diagflags0Mask>
                            <OptionToggles>0</OptionToggles>
                        </CamConfiguration>
                    </CamConfigurations>
                    ]]>
                </Configuration>
            </Device>
            <Device>
                <Role>camera3</Role>
                <Address clr-type="int32">23</Address>
                <Impl>Rasp.Core.RaspCamComponent,Rasp.Core</Impl>
                <Configuration>
                    <![CDATA[
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                    <CamConfigurations>
                        <CamConfiguration TargetProductNumber="711">
                            <Diagflags0Mask>2024</Diagflags0Mask>
                            <OptionToggles>0</OptionToggles>
                        </CamConfiguration>
                    </CamConfigurations>
                    ]]>
                </Configuration>
            </Device>
        </Devices>
    </Cambus>
    <ProcedureBasePath></ProcedureBasePath>
</DeviceConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a compiler error.  The compiler has no way of knowing the structure of your XML document.  This has to be done at run time.

You can have the compiler generate code to do it at run time by using the `dynamic` compile-time type.  Using `var` in the fourth line of your code sample causes the compile-time type of the variable to be `object`.  Instead, try

```
if (xmlSettings.TryGetValue("Cambus", out dynamic value))
//...
```

That will fix the compiler error.

Incidentally, if you declare `expandobj` as `dynamic` instead of `ExpandoObject`, you can use `expandobj.Cambus` instead of `((IDictionary<string, object>)expandobj).TryGetValue("Cambus", out value)`.  However, that will throw if `"Cambus"` is missing, so you might want to stick with `TryGetValue`.  If you do, though, you'll still want to change the key line to `((IDictionary<string, dynamic>)expandobj).TryGetValue("Cambus", out value)`.